# How to prove that if $|A| = \mathfrak{c}$ and $|B| \lt \mathfrak{c}$ then $|A\setminus B| = \mathfrak{c}$?

Tags: set-theory

How to prove that if $|A| = \mathfrak{c}$ and $|B| \lt \mathfrak{c}$ then $|A\setminus B| = \mathfrak{c}$ (without assumption that continuum hpothesis is ture)? I've tried using Cantor-Bernstein theorem but I don't have idea how to prove that $\mathfrak{c} \leq|A\setminus B|$. Also I've managed to prove it with assumpton of the continuum hpothesis.

Comment: If you can use the result that states that $|S\cup T|=\max\{|S|,|T|\}$, assume $|A\setminus B|<c$. What happens to $|(A\setminus B )\cup B|$?

Comment: Then $|(A \setminus B) \cup B| < \mathfrak{c}$ but $A \subseteq (A \setminus B) \cup B$ therefore $\mathfrak{c} \leq |(A \setminus B) \cup B|$ and it is a contradiction. But where does $|S \cup T| = max\{|S|, |T|\}$ come from?

Comment: @R.V.N. Yes, using the more general result, that the same proposition holds for **every** infinite cardinal, you can prove that it holds for $\mathfrak c$. This doesn't seem seem very illuminating to me.

Comment: How do you prove this assuming CH? I suspect the same proof, with minor modifications, should work in the general case.

Comment: I suppose you knoe that $\mathfrak c^2=\mathfrak c$? Using that you can easily show that, if $|A|=\mathfrak c$ and $|B|\lt\mathfrak c$, then there is a surjective map $f:A\setminus B\to A$. Then by the axiom of choice there is an injective map $g:A\to A\setminus B$, so $|A\setminus B|\ge|A|=\mathfrak c$.

Comment: @tomasz Under CH we just have to prove that the union of two countable sets is countable,  which is easier.

Comment: The general result I posted doesn't need to assume CH. It's enough with Choice Axiom. If you want a proof I can also post here.

Comment: @R.V.N. You can post it here, it would help me a lot.

Comment: @tomasz I've used the fact that union of two countable sets is countable and reasoning similar to that in my comment.

Comment: @bof: Interestingly enough, AC is kind of necessary here. Monro proved that it is consistent with ZF that $\Bbb R$ is the union of two sets, both of which are smaller than $\frak c$, indeed in that model any set which cannot be well-ordered has such a decomposition.

Comment: Another way to put it: Konig's theorem (based on the axiom of choice) tells us that, if $|A|\lt|C|$ and $|B|\lt|D|$, then $|A\cup B|\lt|C\times D|$. Hence, if $|A|\lt|\mathbb R|$ and $|B|\lt|\mathbb R|$, then $|A\cup B|\lt|\mathbb R\times\mathbb R|=|\mathbb R|$.